# Solr: Handling starting and trailing whitespace when using splitBy to populate a multi valued field

Tags: solr

I'm using splitBy to populate a multi valued field. There are whitespaces in the result, and I would like to remove them.

In the db:

| Name | City |
| --- | --- |
| "Peter" | "City A,City B,City C\n" |
| "Mary" | "City A, City C , City D" |

My config:

<field sourceColName="City" column="City" splitBy=","  />

My result:

"City": [
"City A",
"City B",
"City C\n"
]

"City": [
"City A",
" City C ",
" City D"
]

I would like to get the following result:

"City": [
"City A",
"City B",
"City C"
]

"City": [
"City A",
"City C",
"City D"
]

How can I remove the starting and trailing whitespace?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a DIH configuration file based on the `field` and as it seems you're transforming the values to be stored and not the tokens themselves - what is your source for the data? It's usually easier to do the transformation there, or if you need to it in DIH, apply a ScriptTransformer. DIH has also been removed from Solr 9, so you'll either have to use the community version in the future or migrate to a new solution.

Comment: The data is from MySQL database and I cannot edit the source data.

Comment: You can use `TRIM` in MySQL to get any whitespace and the ends removed, but since you're splitting the column yourself, that won't handle your second case. Use a script transformer to run a small javascript snippet to trim any ending whitespace for each value.

Comment: Use mysql replace function before the split. So you can replace SPACE COMMA SPACE with a COMMA and COMMA SPACE with a SPACE.

Comment: Thank you, using mysql replace function works fine.